# How many pictures does iPhone 3G(not 3GS) take in one second?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

There is an iPhone App: iVideoCamera (http://labs.laan.com/blog/2010/01/the-ivideocamera-update-approved/), I am wondering what is the way it uses to reach the function that performing video recording on iPhone 3G?

Write an iPhone program to take several pictures in one seconds? But I think it is not possible to take more than 15 pictures in one second. Does anyone have any idea about this ?

Answer (score 0):

About ten frames per second at full resolution (optimally). The CPU isn't fast enough to encode in real-time. The storage is so slow, so you wouldn't want to stream to "disk." Bus performance is also lacking.

The iPhone 3GS has hardware support & acceleration for video. It was never intended for lesser models. Existing "video" apps simply take multiple pictures and sometimes audio too.

Short of jail-breaking for 50% better "frame rate," there isn't anything you can do. Well, there's always solder, custom circuitry and hacking up the firmware. Or... you can kick down the resolution to postage stamp size.